# Unable to Open Anaconda navigator - ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageQt' from 'PIL.ImageQt'

Tags: anaconda

I am trying to open Anaconda Navigator, but unable to.

I tried to open it using anaconda prompt using the command
`anaconda-navigator`
Upon trying this, I am getting the following error

> 

*from anaconda_navigator.widgets.tabs.community import CommunityTab
File "C:\Users...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\tabs\community.py", line 23, in 
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
ImportError: cannot import name 'ImageQt' from 'PIL.ImageQt' (C:\Users...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageQt.py)*